# laravel generate ics file is not showing proper format in outlook

Tags: php, laravel, outlook, laravel-5.1, icalendar

Can anyone help me on this? I wasted too much time on it.but not getting any solution. Actually, I'm creating ics file in php using laravel framework. 
Below is the format which I'm using to create ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test TM//NONSGML Test//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Name;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:emailid@test.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20160416T095328Z
DESCRIPTION:test description
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160417T023000Z
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20160417T030000Z
DTSTAMP:20160416T095328Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20160416T095328Z
ORGANIZER;CN=name:mailto:email@test.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:Test
SUMMARY:subject
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:20160416T095328-17250.com
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:Confirmed
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:Confirmed
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT60M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

and when I'm sending this as attachement in laravel, then I'm getting mail in outlook with below screenshot detail
[image]

But I need this in following format.
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your installation of Outlook rather than PHP or Laravel.

Use a validator and you will see your file is fine: http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

Have you confirmed this by trying on a different computer that has outlook? If not, I would suggest you narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked ics file with your provided link and it validated my file. And also I checked this other computer getting same issue. Have you any idea what I'm missing here.

Comment: It no longer sounds like a programming issue if the file is valid